# getting multiple data for one Id in an array in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I have 3 tables say `tab1, tab2 and tab3`.
Now tab1 have some unique key say `idKey`.
tab2 have some columns `idKey, Ques`. tab3 have columns `idKey, Ans`.
here tab2 and tab3 have some question and answer(anywhere between 1 to 5) corresponding to idKey in tab1.
example data:

```
tab1:
idKey:
1
2
tab2:
idkey Ques
1 q11
1 q12
2 q21
2 q22
2 q23
tab3:
idKey Ans
1 a11
1 a12
2 a21
2 a22
2 a23
```

now I want to fetch all data such that while fetching, I will get only 2 rows in return with idKey,array(Ques),array(Ans).
something like this:

```
select a.idKey,array_agg(b.Ques),array_agg(c.Ans) from tab1 a, tab2 b, tab 3
```

required output:

```
idKey Ques Ans
1 [q11,q12] [a11,a12]
2 [q21,q22,q23] [a21,a22,a23]
```

now I want this ques ans data in a json
something like:

```
select idKey,array_agg(row_to_json(Ques, Ans)) as QuesAns from tab1, tab2, tab3.
```

so that I can get output as :

```
idKey QuesAns
1 [{"Ques":"q11", "Ans":"a11"},{"Ques":"q12","Ans":"a12"}]
2 [{"Ques":"q21", "Ans":"a21"},{"Ques":"q22", "Ans":"a22"},{"Ques":"q23", "Ans":"a23"}]
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT**

I forget to add a sequence. so tab2 and tab3 also have another column for sequence say `seq`and values are:

```
tab2:
    idkey seq Ques
    1 1 q11
    1 2 q12
    2 1 q21
    2 2 q22
    2 3 q23
    tab3:
    idKey seq Ans
    1 1 a11
    1 2 a12
    2 1 a21
    2 2 a22
    2 3 a23
```

so now query should be like:

```
select idKey,array_agg(row_to_json(Ques, Ans)) as QuesAns from tab1 a, tab2 b, tab3 c where b.seq=c.seq
```

output expected is same as mentioned above.

Comment: What is relation between tab2 and tab3 ? Means how are you identifying  questions and its related answers.

Comment: idKey from tab1 is reference key for tab2 and tab3. actually there is another key to identify sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Table Creation:

```
create table tab1(idkey int);
create table tab2(idkey int,seq int, ques char(10));
create table tab3(idkey int,seq int, ans char(10));
```

Insert Statement:

```
insert into tab1 values(1),(2);
insert into tab2 values(1,1,'q11'),(1,2,'q12'),
(2,1,'q21'),(2,2,'q22'),(2,3,'q23');
insert into tab3 values(1,1,'a11'),(1,2,'a12'),
(2,1,'a21'),(2,2,'a22'),(2,3,'a23');
```

Query 1:

```
select tab2.idkey,
array_agg((select row_to_json(_) from (select tab2.ques as "Ques", tab3.ans as "Ans") as _)) as value
from tab2 join tab3 on tab2.idkey = tab3.idkey 
and tab2.seq = tab3.seq
group by tab2.idkey
```

Query 2:

```
select tab2.idkey, 
array_agg(json_build_object('Ques',ques, 'Ans',ans)) as value
from tab2 join tab3 on tab2.idkey = tab3.idkey 
and tab2.seq = tab3.seq
group by tab2.idkey
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0e348/27)